# How to set different height to children of VBox

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to create a `TreeView` where each `TreeCell` represents a statement in the program. By invoking `setGraphics`, I want to replace the default cell with a customized `Node`, like the following figure.

[image]

I am using a `VBox` as all the children are placed vertically. The *Header* and *Footer* are 2 tiny areas reserved for Drag-and-Drop operations. e.g. I can drag-and-drop a new statement before the current one by moving the cursor over its header.

I want to use `Label` for header and footer, and I want to limit their height to 2 pixels, so I have tried:

```
public VBox getTestContainer() {
    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    Label header = new Label();
    header.setPrefHeight(2);
    header.setPrefWidth(200);
    ... ... ...
    vbox.getChildren().add(header, ..., footer);
}

public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    Group root = new Group();
    root.getChildren().add(getTestBlock());
    stage.setTitle("Test");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 300));
    stage.show();
}
```

To make sure that the `VBox` is not resized by other layout pane, I have simply put it in a `Group`.

The `setPrefWidth` works, it gives me a 200-pixel wide `Label` and `VBox`, but the `setPrefHeight` doesn't. As you can see the height of the header is much larger than 2 pixels.

[image]

My question is how to correctly set the height of `Label`?

Comment: I don't see how it is possible to write a label that is 2pixels tall. `setPrefWidth()` probably failed because it couldn't find any ways to render a probably 12 pixels tall text in a 2 pixels tall space.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Did you try header.setMinHeight(2) ?

Comment: @Jai I am not gonna put any text in *header*.

Comment: @kleopatra Sorry about that, I have added more code,

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine No, I have tried both `setMinHeight` and `setMaxHeight`, none of these methods worked, and I just don't get it, isn't `setPrefWidth` supposed to set the preferred width ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `prefHeight` (or `maxHeight`) to a value smaller than the computed min height of the `Label` still results in the lable's minimum height being used as smallest possible height for the `Label`. This minimum height is based on the font size.

```
header.setFont(Font.font(2));
```

Would reduce the calculated minimum height.

Since it doesn't seem like you're trying to add any text to those nodes, just use `Region`s instead of `Label`s as first and last child of the `VBox`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, really helpful. So basically, `Label` calculate its preferred size based on the font size. I'd like to know how did you discover this, I have read the javadoc of `Label`, the calculation of preferred size is not explained at all.

Comment: @vesontio I started with an educated guess (the height is similar to the text height) and tested, if this indeed was true. Note that `Label` itself does not contain the logic for calculating it's size constraints. It's the skin (`LabelSkin` = the result of the `createDefaultSkin` method) that contains this logic. A different skin could choose to calculate those constraints in a different way and `Control`s support assigning a custom skin via the `skin` property.

Comment: Thank you fabian, I really need more exercises to have a better understanding of Javafx :)